# Visual studio seems to be broken

Tags: c++, arrays, class, visual-c++

So i am new with visual studio because I tried to make a 3d game engine using gdi+ (mentioning since it throws some errors but initially i dealt with them, maybe its interfering with the code in some way but im not sure). I got everything set up and code was working properly until i decided to implement this class:

`

```
class kostka
{

    public:
        wierzcholek3D ldf(0, 0, 0);
        wierzcholek3D rdf(1, 0, 0);
        wierzcholek3D luf(0, 1, 0);
        wierzcholek3D ruf(1, 1, 0);
        wierzcholek3D ldb(0, 0, 1);
        wierzcholek3D lub(0, 1, 1);
        wierzcholek3D rdb(1, 0, 1);
        wierzcholek3D rub(1, 1, 1);
        //n
        trojkat n1(ldf, rdf, luf);
        trojkat n2(ruf, rdf, luf);
        //w
        trojkat w1(ldf, luf, ldb);
        trojkat w2(lub, luf, ldb);
        //e
        trojkat e1(rdf, ruf, rdb);
        trojkat e2(rub, ruf, rdb);
        //s
        trojkat s1(ldb, rdb, lub);
        trojkat s2(rub, rdb, lub);
        //t
        trojkat t1(luf, ruf, lub);
        trojkat t2(rub, ruf, lub);
        //b
        trojkat b1(ldf, rdf, ldb);
        trojkat b2(rdb, rdf, ldb);
};`

which is a sort of container for a cube where wierzcholek3D is supposed to be a verticle and trojkat are triangles making up the faces of the cube, also there is the verticle declaration:

`
class wierzcholek3D
{

    public:
        float x, y, z;
        wierzcholek3D(float xc, float yc, float zc)
        {
            x = xc;
            y = yc;
            z = zc;
        }
        wierzcholek3D() {}
      //~wierzcholek2D();
};

Also separately i have this error about an array:

    class projmatrix{
    public:
        float nera = 0.1, fra = 1000, fov = 90, aratio = HEIGHT / (float)WIDTH;
        float fovtan = 1 / tanf((fov * 0.5 / 180) * 3.14159);
        float m[4][4] = {0};
        m[0][0] = aratio * fovtan;
        m[1][1] = fovtan;
        m[2][2] = fra/(fra-nera);
        m[3][2] = (-fra*nera)/(fra-nera);
        m[2][3] = 1;
};
```

Here you have the list of errors i got:

```
1>D:\visual studio\prog\WindowsProject1\WindowsProject1\WindowsProject1.cpp(103,17): error C2087: 'm': missing subscript
```

error about the array and i googled it and it doesn't appear like something that i have done might have caused it or so I think for now.

```
1>D:\visual studio\prog\WindowsProject1\WindowsProject1\WindowsProject1.cpp(67,27): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
```

dont know how is this caused maybe i am stupid or bad

Anyway any sort of help would be appreciated because I spend a whole day to figure it out and I am really mad at myself because its probably sort of a noob error
`

Comment: Are you trying to execute statement in a class declaration body?!? That's far from valid c++ ...

Comment: Which line is 103 ? Which is 67 ?

Comment: The error about `m` is because you can't have arbitrary statements outside a function. Ideone shows that here: [https://ideone.com/n06v0p](https://ideone.com/n06v0p)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is widely used. It is **extremely** unlikely to be so broken. The cause is most probably an error on your part. You'd have to isolate it.

- Concentrate on the *first* error flagged. Often an error causes a cascade of them.
- Try to cut out as much as possible of the file, keeping the error. That helps focus on what is wrong.
- A short MWE (minimal working example, better non-working example) makes any would-be answerer's job much easier, and will net you many more quality answers. Invest a half hour in cutting down the example, win days of waiting for answers.

Here I'd suspect your `float m[4][4] = {0}`, as you try to initialize a $4 \times 4$ array with a single value. Perhaps some compilers allow that, I'm no language lawyer.

Comment: I dealt with everything, also sorry for misleading you and writing that vs is broken I think I should change it, also sorry for wasting your time it was a rookie mistake :/ it's my first take on longer-than-100-lines project using classes. Anyway thank you all for pointing that I am just trying to do something really stupid but I realized it now ^^